# django help login check

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication

view.py

```
username = request.POST['username']
password = request.POST['password']

user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user is not None:
    if user.is_active:
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('index')
```

login success my view.py

global_header.html

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
{% endif %}
```

However, login verification is not possible globally there are two
cases.

```
return render(request, page_name, param) # if user.is_authenticated return True
```

if another case.

```
return HttpResponse(page.render(param)) # if user.is_authenticated return False
```

So I can not use HttpResponse?

Comment: Can you please explain the two cases that you mentioned?

Comment: But what is `page.render`? Why are you doing that? You don't seem to be passing the user object there so not surprisingly the template will not know if the it is authenticated.

Comment: page.render means `page = loader.get_template('header.html')`